# OpenLayers page is only accessible in IE

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I have developed web map application using OpenLayers and GeoServer. Geoserver is installed on production server on port 8080. It works fine in Internet Explorer and all the GIS layers are easily accessible. But my application does not run in any other explorer e.g Chrome or firefox etc.

can anybody explain why it not works in any explorer except IE, Where is the problem ?

Comment: Perhaps this would be better off migrated to SO or ServerFault?

Comment: I have Geoserver & Openlayers working with Firefox, IE-7-8-9 and chrome without issue. Likely to be meta tag in the header - <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> & <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

Comment: Edit your original question and provide some sample code. How do you expect anyone to know where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe firefox doesn't have the same proxy settings as IE.

More information would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the code you wrote. IE is not W3C compliant. You should never code a web application with IE first but with a browsers which support web standrads, and then only hack it if needed to fit with IE.

Since you have done the work yet, you can try to debug your app using firefox with the firebug extension.